# pdf generation in PHP is not working

Tags: php, pdf

I am using fpdf for generating pdf. But it is not working.

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdff = $pdf->output('tmp\tmp_file.pdf',"D");
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($pdff));
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename="some_pdf_to_download.pdf"');
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Pragma: public'); 
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
readfile('tmp\tmp_file.pdf');
echo $pdff;
```

This is the code I am using. I am getting the output "%PDF 3.......".

Comment: Hello and Welcome on SO, please take some time to take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), then [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and finally provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

The "D" option to FPDF outputs to the browser **including all the headers required** to offer the file as a download.

`readfile` outputs the content of the file at the specified location on the server.

It looks like you expect `echo $pdff;` to output the PDF contents as well.

In effect you are trying to output the headers twice and the PDF body three times.

Your headers are also confusing. You specify inline disposition but include a filename for download.

The simplest solution would be to replace everything from `$pdff` onwards with:

```
$pdf->Output('some_pdf_to_download.pdf', 'D');
```

if you want the user to be prompted to download the file or

```
$pdf->Output('', 'I');
```

to render the PDF inline.